# tableFooterView not aligning itself properly at the bottom of the table

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, tablefooterview

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with `UITableView`. I've setup a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. `UITableView` contains a `tableHeaderView`, `tableFooterView`, a section footer view, and a couple of `UITableViewCell`s with dynamic heights.

The problem is that the `tableFooterView` appears somewhere in the middle of the table (hovering over the cell), instead of aligning itself at the bottom of the table's content. Apparently, table's `contentSize` property is also returning incorrect content size (specifically the height).

The custom section footer view, however, is appearing in the right place (and below the actual `tableFooterView` -- which is hovering in the middle of the table).

Any ideas what's going on?

Note: My custom table-view (with dynamic height handing using Auto Layouts) is showing a "Ambiguous Layout: 2 views are vertically ambiguous." warning, but it's resizing correctly at run-time.

The table setup is pretty simple:

```
// Set table header/footer view
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.myTableHeaderView;
self.mainTableView.tableFooterView = self.myTableFooterView;

// Table delegate methods
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self heightForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [MyCustomCell defaultHeight];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {
        return self.mySectionFooterView;
    }

    return [UIView new];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {
        return [self heightForSectionFooterView];
    }

    return 0.01f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an extra section with just the header and footer (and no rows), to get the desired results. Maybe the auto-layouts are acting weird. I'm still getting the "Ambiguous Layout: 2 views are vertically ambiguous.", but the UI looks good.

Comment: The tableFooterView alignment issue is still happening in iOS 8.1. Your solution worked... using a section header with no rows. Huzzah!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to set **footerView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth**

Example code:

```
let footerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: MyFooterView.self), owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! MyFooterView
footerView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 80))
footerView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like for now estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: messes with footer views:

https://twitter.com/steipete/status/420538600384888832

Comment: So, I'm not the only one. Good to know. :)

Comment: It took me ages to finally realize it was not my program that was the issue!!! So much for thinking the framework would work out of the box!